# Grep variable in for loop

Tags: bash

I want to grep a specific line for each loop in a for loop. I've already looked on the internet to see an answer to my problem, I tried them but it doesn't seem to work for me... And I don't find what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code :

```
for n in 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 ; do
    for U in 1 10 100 ; do
        for L in 2 4 6 8 ; do
i=0
cat results/output_iteration/occ_"$L"_"$n"_"$U"_it"$i".dat
for k in $(seq 1 1 $L) ; do
        ${'var'.$k}=`grep "   $k    " results/output_iteration/occ_"$L"_"$n"_"$U"_it"$i".dat | tail -n 1`
done
```

which gives me :

```
%
%
%  site    density        double occupancy                
    1     0.49791021     0.03866179
    2     0.49891438     0.06077808
    3     0.50426102     0.05718336
    4     0.49891438     0.06077808
./run_deviation_functionL.sh: line 109: ${'var'.$k}=`grep "   $k    " results/output_iteration/occ_"$L"_"$n"_"$U"_it"$i".dat | tail -n 1`: bad substitution
```

Then, I would like to take only the density number, with something like:

```
 ${'density'.$k}=`echo "${'var'.$k:10:10}"  | bc -l`
```

Anyone knows the reason why it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `declare` to create variable names from variables:

```
declare density$k="`...`"
```

Use the variable indirection to retrieve them:

```
var=var$k
echo ${!var:10:10}
```

Comment: So if I understood well, I have to do     `declare var$k=`grep "   $k    " file.dat | tail -n 1 ` ? But when I do this, I have this kind of error : ./run.sh: line 109: declare: `1': not a valid identifier
./run.sh: line 109: declare: `0.49791021': not a valid identifier
./run.sh: line 109: declare: `0.03866179': not a valid identifier

Comment: And when I do than var=var$k, echo $var ; it gives me "var1", "var2"... And not the line I wanted to grep

Comment: @B_runo: Double quote the `...` if spaces are involved: ``declare var$k="`...`"``.